# Two buttons trigger the same function after initial clicks

Tags: java, javascript, html, jakarta-ee, struts

I have two buttons, "Search" and "Matrix Search". when I FIRST click on the "Search" button, it does what it's supposed to do. But if I click on "Search"
button after I click on "Matrix Search" button, it invokes the matrixSearch() function. Why does this happen? Does it have anything to do with scope?

Following is the sequence of my actions:

Click Button A---> Works fine(invokes function A)

Click Button B---> Works fine(invokes function B)

Click Button A---> Calls Button B onClick function (invokes function B) Why??

jsp file:

```
<input type="submit" title="Search" value="Search" 
                name="Search" id="Search"
                onClick="clickSearchButton();" />
<input type="button" class="buttonIndent" value="Matrix Search" 
                onclick="matrixSearch()" />

function matrixSearch(){
    //some Code omitted for simiplicity
    form.action = '<%= request.getContextPath() %>/matrixSearch.do';
}

function clickSearchButton(){
    form.action = "<%= request.getContextPath()%>/search.do";
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    document.form.submit();
}
```

Struts configuratin file:

```
<action path="/search" type="com.action.MyAction"
     name="form" scope="session" validate="false"
     parameter="search">
     <forward name="success" path="tile.view"/> 
</action>

<action path="/matrixSearch"
    type="com.action.MyAction"
    name="form" parameter="searchMatrix"
    scope="request" validate="false">
    <forward name="success" path="/matrix_search.jsp"/>
    <forward name="failure" path="tile.view"/>  
</action>
```

Comment: Why are you sure it calls the wrong function? Just because it redirects to the wrong address? Check again, it might be related to your code falling in a condition where your form's action does not update as expected. Use some alerts or web developer to debug

Comment: @Alfabravo You're right. There was an error in my javascript function. I didn't see your comment earlier. I only saw it after I solved the problem. Had I seen your comment, it would have saved me a lot of time.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. There were two problems. The first problem was the with the following statement: 
form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

For some reason, this attribute was being persisted even during my next button click. 
So I added the following in my other function

form.setAttribute("target", "_self");

The second problem was there was a problem in my clickSearchFunction(). This function is long, so I didn't write the whole code here in my question. One of the statement in the function was accessing a field that I had deleted because I didn't need it anymore. 
I just deleted that line and it worked like a charm.

Thanks to every body who took a shot at this question.